# Do Karaite Jewish hold of the 39 melachos?

Tags: non-rabbinic-judaism

Do Karaite Jewish hold of the 39 melachos? 
I've tried to get information about it and I couldn't find. I found that they deny 39 melachos, but it doesn't say to me if they have more melachos or less.

Comment: The Karaites are famous for being *too strict* about some things that rabbinic Jews allowed, most notably leaving candles lit, leaving hot food up, and allowing for eruvs. (Maimonides says "any adult Jew who believes in eruvs" can effect one; he was excluding Karaites with that last phrase.) I'm not aware of things the Oral Law *prohibited* on Sabbath that the Karaites permitted, but I'm not very familiar with Karaites.

Comment: @Shalom do they hold of the 39 melachos?

Comment: Here is written by Magen Avroham that they practice Shabbath: הקראים שומרים שבת, לכן מיילדים אותם בשבת (מג"א סי' ש"ל ד'). http://www.daat.ac.il/encyclopedia/value.asp?id1=2319

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am a Karaite Jew (studied in and raised in the Karaite tradition). No, historically, the Karaites had no concept of the 39 melachot. In short, melacha is a word that is not defined in the Torah. The general karaite view is that words that are not defined are common words and are words that were known at the time of the torah. So, melacha - being a "common" word (not a defined term) would not have a specific, highly technical meaning of 39 forbidden categories of action.

you can read more about shabbat below.

https://www.karaites.org/uploads/7/4/1/3/7413835/mikdash_meat_section_3_shabbat.pdf

Comment: Thank you for your answer! the link is broken.

Comment: Interesting. Works for me: You can also get at it this way: https://www.karaites.org/reading-room.html

Comment: Anything else needed on this?

Comment: Thank you. I had to use VPN in order to open it. By the way, if you can answer this question I'll be thankful: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/117828/how-many-threads-in-the-tzitzit-of-karaite. Or maybe you know a site of which people can ask questions and learn more about the Karaite.