# How many threads in the 'Tzitzit' of Karaites?

Tags: non-rabbinic-judaism

According to the rabbinical tradition, there are 8 threads in each side of the Tzitzit.

How many threads in the 'Tzitzit' of Karaites?

Comment: [Here's apparently a picture](http://abluethread.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/final-karaite-fact-cards_page_05-666x1024.png) of what they wear. Hard to count how many. @ABlueThread

Comment: a better resource than asking non-Karaites about Karaite practice might be to consult with a Karaite https://www.karaite-korner.org/tzitzit.shtml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: Karaite tzitzit]

From this image on the [website](http://www.karaite.org.il/karaite/tzizit) of the World Karaite Organization, it seems that each side has two cords: one white and one blue.

Based on this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5KbwmZQnsE4&ab_channel=MGRpdx), it looks like each cord is made up of four strings, much like the rabbinical tzitzit.

---

For more info on the subject and process:

http://www.theancientsblue.com/tying-tzitziot.html

https://yehuditrose.com/seeing-a-different-judaism/

https://www.karaite-korner.org/tzitzit.shtml

Answer (score 3):

as far as I know there is no "required" number of threads. Most of the ones in my possession have 4 blue and 4 white threads. (Maybe all of them.)

In case anyone is interested, I have a learning on techellet (thought it does not touch on the number of threads). https://youtu.be/sI-sBMn7wSk?t=1387

Comment: But it's written in Tora to have 'Petil' (singular) tcheleth. Isn't it? (honestly, I expected Karaite interpretation to be more attached to what written). Thank you for your answers and for the video (check also 27:00 min.).

Comment: @A Blue Thread: If you ever see this please answer my question here: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/94910/do-karaite-jews-still-believe-that-adulterers-should-get-the-death-penalty